# Have any chrome flags, that auto continue long running script?

Tags: javascript, long-running-processes, google-chrome-flags

For example I see popup message saying:

> script make your browser more slow

and buttons <kbd>stop script</kbd> or <kbd>continue script/wait script</kbd>

Can I use any chrome flag that chrome auto press "continue script" or not show me this message, and not break the script?

Comment: Probably not, as all the nice people would use it.. instead don't write code which blocks the render. If the browser intervenes then your doing it wrong. Can you show some code which is causing the issue?

Comment: there arent any flags that would accomplish what you need

Comment: @LawrenceCherone my code is babylonjs 3D mesh building. The array of little elements subtract from one big template(inside for loop... and little parts array have 128 +- elements). The result is flat wheel track , and impossible do this parallel... every next step must have incoming base element from previous subtraction + new little element which will be subtrackt from base. I think with incoming WebGL , browser developers need think about way to unlock this message. Because 3D always take lot of source.

Comment: `and impossible do this parallel`,, That's fine, just try and look into splitting up and doing `async`...